# Linux output to text file

Tags: linux, io

Hi I am working on a college project, intro to linux. I am trying to get my shell script to output into a text file but I cam getting `command not found`.
Does anyone see a problem in my command?

```
jamesbrannigan@ip-172-31-20-166:~/Project$ question2.sh > jamesbrannigan.txt
question2.sh: command not found
```

Thanks!

Comment: The reason for this problem should have been covered in the class. Ask for your tuition back.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly because `question2.sh` isn't in the path. That's pretty reasonable, if only "regular" programs are in the path.

Assuming it's in the current directory (which is likely *not* on the path), just make that explicit using `.` to refer to the current directory:

```
./question2.sh > jamesbrannigan.txt
```

Note that this doesn't have anything to do with where the output goes - you'd see the same thing if you just ran `question2.sh`.